# How can I make a custom border width not resize when zoomed in?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, zooming, blink

When I set the border width to thin/medium/thick and zoom in the page in Chrome, the border size appears the same no matter what my zoom level is.

When I set the size to something else, such as 2px, this no longer happens, and the border starts looking bigger as I zoom in. Is it possible to set the size to something other than the thin/medium/thick presets, but still have their size not depend on the zoom level?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. On Firefox even with `thin/medium/thick` the border size will resize based on the page zoom and this is the correct behavior. I think this is a Chrome bug because when the page zoom level increase every element with a **absolute** unit scale with the page, exept the `border-width`.